# AS3 Flash URLRequest not working upon export

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, urlrequest

This simple login form works within the test environment of CS6 (Flash 11.4) but upon exporting does not work. I've narrowed down the issue to the actual `URLRequest` not working properly. Hopefully somebody can shed some light!

Many thanks, Nick :)

**AS3**

```
login.loginSubmit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){

    if(login.loginPassword.text!="Password" && login.loginPassword.text!=""){

        login.loginSubmit.enabled = false;

        // Begin URL setup for login
        var loginVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables("email="+login.loginEmail.text+"&password="+login.loginPassword.text); 
        var loginRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        loginRequest.url = "login.php";
        loginRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
        loginRequest.data = loginVariables;
        var loginLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loginLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        loginLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loginHandler);         

        function loginHandler(event:Event):void {
            if(loginLoader.data.passed=="true"){

                var hideInitial:Tween = new Tween(uiInitial, "x", Strong.easeOut, 6, -315, 0.5, true);
                hideInitial.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, function(){
                    member.data.email = loginLoader.data.email;
                    member.data.fname = loginLoader.data.fname;
                    member.data.lname = loginLoader.data.lname;
                    member.flush();
                });

            }else{
                                 trace("error");
            }
        } 
        // Send PHP/SQL request
        loginLoader.load(loginRequest); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the network access for your published SWF. Go to Publish Settings for Flash (.swf) and Set the "Local playback security" settings to "Access Network Only".

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the solution, but it still doesn't work upon publishing/export. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Turns out that there is both a local and external URLRequest, causing trouble with the settings. I've made both the same (external) and of course hosted them on the same domain as the Flash, now works.**