# AS3 MouseEvent.CLICK not working in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, urlrequest

The ActionScript 3.0 code below works when tested in Adobe Flash CS6, however when tested in a browser the code does not work. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
buttonInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent){
    flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://facebook.com"), "_blank"); 
    trace("link clicked");
},false,0,true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had 'Local playback security' set to 'Access local files only' I changed it to 'Access network on only' and it works. This post helped [AS3 Flash URLRequest not working upon export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061474/as3-flash-urlrequest-not-working-upon-export?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The event listener's probably being garbage-collected.  You need to change your code to one of the following:

```
buttonInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent){
    flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://facebook.com"), "_blank"); 
    trace("link clicked");
}); // (false, 0, false)
```

or:

```
    buttonInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick,false,0,true);
.
.
.
private function onClick(pEvent:MouseEvent):void
{
    flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://facebook.com"), "_blank"); 
    trace("link clicked");
}
```

Comment: I've tried both an neither works. I've event tried the code below and it does not work. buttonInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
 navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://facebook.com"), "_blank");
}

Comment: Does it go inside the event handler? Do you see the trace?

Comment: It was vulnerable to garbage collection and did need to be changed like that, but it sounds like there's another issue deeper in the context of your code.